# How to use "by" in the meaning of "according to", "extra info" and "as a result"?

Tags: word-usage

I've found the following definition for "by", but I am not sure HOW and WHEN I can use "by" in such meaning.

[Definition of "by" in Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/by_1)

1. from what something shows or says; according to something
2. used for giving more information about where somebody comes from, what somebody does, etc.
3. used before particular nouns without the, to say that something happens as a result of something

I'd like to know some tips and more information about the above meaning of "by".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The link you provide gives examples of the different uses. What more information do you need? (1) _It's ten o'clock by my watch_ - according to the time it shows. (2) _He is a doctor by profession_. (3) _It happened by chance_.

Comment: Actually, I'd like a general rule to use "by": grammar, synonyms,...

Comment: Prepositions have multiple idiomatic uses which can't always be explained by grammar rules. You just have to accept that 'that's how we say it'.